# angularjs template not displaying

Tags: angularjs

i made a basic custom directive using angular js. I can log the scope to the console, but it will not display the template inside the markup. I am fiddling with inherited, shared, and isolated scopes and wondering if I have my directive nested wrongly?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('StudentController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.student = {
        name: "dj",
        age: 32,
        subject: [
            "math",
            "geography"
        ]
    }
 
    $scope.setGrade = function (student) {
        student.grade = "A+"
    }
        //console.log($scope.student);
              myApp.directive('studentDir',function(){
            
           return{
               template:"{{student.age}} years old!",
               replace: true,
               restrict: 'E',
               controller: function($scope){
                   //console.log($scope);
               }
           } 
        });
 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="StudentController">
   
    <student-dir></student-dir>

    
    
    
    </div>
      
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to wrap your template with a `<div>`

```
return {
    template:"<div>{{student.age}} years old!</div>",
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope){
        //console.log($scope);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If your code is as you have posted above, then you need to declare your directive outside of your controller as follows:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('StudentController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.student = {
        name: "dj",
        age: 32,
        subject: [
           "math",
           "geography"
        ]
    }

    $scope.setGrade = function (student) {
        student.grade = "A+"
    }

}]);

myApp.directive('studentDir',function(){
    return{
        template:"<div>{{student.age}} years old!</div>",
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope){
            //console.log($scope);
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `replace: true` from your directive will make it working. Because when you're using `replace: true`(this has been already deprecated though) you have to single DOM element in your `template`, as `$compile` service needs only single root to compile. But here you have `{{student.age}} years old!` serveral DOM nodes.

[**Demo 1**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XNmBmRhon7THIOP3mVLZ?p=preview)

---

Or wrap your template content with some element wrapper like `span`/`div`

```
template:"<span>{{student.age}} years old!</span>",
```

[**Demo 2**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ltRgOiNNiVMjSOzv7PpT?p=preview)

Comment: @Vzupo you just had to remove directive initalization part out of controller. Already covered that in plunker.. I didn't mention in the answer because I thought its mistake while adding code in post

Comment: what are you calling the directive init? the replace:true?

Comment: @Vzupo I meant to say. you had mistakenly put directive inside controller which was wrong.. that you should take out of directive controller.